# React animate component when it render and when its state change

Tags: css, reactjs

For animation i write the code like this but this code is not working for me. Whant to know this is a css problem or my code style needs update. or how to do animation on a component

```js
render: function() {
  var len = Object.keys(Interfaces.previewContainer.state.sourceImg).length;

  var imgContainer = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    imgContainer.push(React.createElement(PreviewImgContainer, {
      key: i,
      flipParentClass: this.state.flipParentClass,
      i_d: 'SelectedTemplate_' + i,
      dataactionstring: 'selecttemplatetype-' + this.state.dataactionstring['src' + i],
      sourceImg: this.state.sourceImg['src' + i],
      ref: 'PreviewImgContainer',
      alter: this.state.alter
    }));

  }
  return (
    React.createElement(
      ReactCSSTransitionGroup, {
        className:'flipParent',
        transitionEnterTimeout: 250,
        transitionLeaveTimeout: 250,
        transitionName: 'flipped' // 'flipParent flipped' is a class name
      },
      React.createElement('div', {
        className: 'previewContainer',
        style: {
          marginLeft: this.state.marginLeft
        },
        ref: 'previewContainer'
      }, imgContainer)
    )
  );
}
```

please let me know where i am making a mistake or where i have to update the code

```css
.flipParent {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease 0s;
  width: 100%;
}
/* .flipped is for flipping (x-axis) the element */

.flipped {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: error is nothing it doesnot show animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to implement these

.flipped-enter

.flipped-enter.flipped-enter-active

.flipped-leave

.flipped-leave.flipped-leave-active

The below screenshot is from [the official react guide](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/animation.html)

[image]